# Manage docker container security patches

Tags: docker

I have some questions concerning security in a dockerized app:

- How can we manage security patches of our docker containers?
- Is there any application/service which lists installed packages per container and if there are any 0day exploits which affect our container?

Comment: "Installed packages" are just calls to `yum`/`apk`/`apt`/etc. in the Dockerfile - how would you approach these questions for a non-Docker situation?

Answer (score 0):

Docker Cloud and Docker Hub [can perform security scans](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/image-scan/) for images in private repositories. There are also third party services like [Anchore](http://anchore.io) that can do the same. These services will scan your Docker images and tell you what packages are installed, any CVEs, etc.

In general, your containers should have exactly the software needed to run your application and nothing else. In general, I suggest focussing on reducing the attack surface of your container images first. Then, you can use the image scanning tools for whatever's left.

Also, you should regularly rebuild your images as upstream tags get refreshed with patches. For example, if your image extends `alpine:3.5`, you should rebuild either as that tag gets updated with patches, or on a regular schedule. Tools like Docker Hub and Anchore can help you with that, too.